# Google Mock: mock fstream object and control of execution in test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, fstream, googletest, googlemock

I need to write some unit test for following function. In order to do that I need to mock ifstream object. I did that but I have a problem with control of execution during test. How can I set value returned by get in 
`while(p_fileDescriptor->get(l_singleByte))`
to eofbit object in one case and to "normal" istream object in another case? I tried some options, but it was not work. Could you help me with that?
Bellow function there is my unit test.
Function to test:

```
void ServerSendFileRequestHandler::sendRequestedFile(std::shared_ptr<std::istream> p_fileDescriptor, int& p_clientSocket) const
{
unsigned int l_msgCounter = 1;
unsigned long long l_byteCounter = 0;
Message l_sendline;
memset(&l_sendline, 0, sizeof(l_sendline));

char l_singleByte;
while(p_fileDescriptor->get(l_singleByte))
{
    checkIfReadByteSucceded(p_fileDescriptor, l_byteCounter);
    l_sendline.payload[l_byteCounter] = l_singleByte;
    l_byteCounter++;

    if(l_byteCounter == PAYLOAD_SIZE)
    {
        std::cout << "Sending message number: " << l_msgCounter << std::endl;
        sendClientSendFileInd(l_sendline, l_byteCounter, p_clientSocket);
        l_msgCounter++;

        l_byteCounter = 0;
        memset(&l_sendline, 0, sizeof(l_sendline));
    }
}

if(l_byteCounter)
{
    std::cout << "Sending message number: " << l_msgCounter << std::endl;
    sendClientSendFileInd(l_sendline, l_byteCounter, p_clientSocket);
    l_msgCounter++;
}
std::cout << "Sending of file is done!" << std::endl;
}
```

My unit test:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include <istream>
using namespace std;
class FstreamMock : public std::istream  
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(get, istream&(char&));
};

using namespace testing;
TEST_F(ServerSendFileRequestHandlerTestSuite, sendRequestedFileTest)
{
    int l_clientSocket = 0;
    std::shared_ptr<FstreamMock> l_fileDescriptor;
    const bool i = false;

    char l_byte;
    //EXPECT_CALL(*l_fileDescriptor, get(_)).WillRepeatedly(ReturnRef(*l_fileDescriptor));
    EXPECT_CALL(*l_fileDescriptor, get(_)).WillRepeatedly(ReturnRef(*l_fileDescriptor);
    m_sut.sendRequestedFile(l_fileDescriptor, l_clientSocket);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your approach is not good. [ifstream::get](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) is not virtual function, so mocking it has not effect that you expect: base `ifstream::get` is called.

Anyway - you should either use `istream` not `ifstream` - in function `ServerSendFileRequestHandler::sendRequestedFile` - and for testing you can just use `stringstream` - it is easy to assert what was written to `stringstream`. You can change this function name to `ServerSendFileRequestHandler::sendRequestedStream`.

```
TEST_F(ServerSendFileRequestHandlerTestSuite, sendRequestedStreamTest)
{
    std::istringstream stream("some input");
    int l_clientSocket = 0;
    const bool i = false;

    char l_byte;
    m_sut.sendRequestedStream(stream, l_clientSocket);
}
```

Or, better - you should create your own abstraction - define your interface, that is something which returns single byte:

```
class IByteStream  
{
public:
    virtual ~IByteStream() = default;
    virtual char get() = 0;
};
```

Then - implementation based on `std::istream`:

```
class StdStreamByteStream : public IByteStream  
{
public:
    StdStreamByteStream(std::istream& is) : is(is) {}        
    char get() override { return is.get(); }
private:
    std::istream& is;
};
```

Then Mock:

```
class ByteStreamMock : public IByteStream  
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(get, char());
};
```

Having these classes - just change your implementation and tests - and it will work.